# How to only match letters that occur more than once in a string, using regex?

Tags: regex, ruby

I am trying to only match letters that appear more than once(twice or more) in a string , using regex for ruby. I came up with the regular expression below but it does not seem to work. I'd appreciate if someone could explain why my regex does not work and tell me how it should be in order for it to work.

```
/[a-z]{2,}/
```

Comment: Why have you tagged C# ruby and perl?

Comment: Do you mean letters that repeat themselves, like `aa`, or any letters (`ab`)? Do they need to be consecutive (so `aba` doesn't count, only `aa`)?  What you have matches a letter, two or more times, so `abc`...

Comment: Hi, zdim. What I want is a regular expression that only matches any letter that occurs 2 times or more in a string. The letter could be anywhere in the string but if it occurs more than once in  a string, only then I want the match. For example: for string = "data", the matched item should only be "a", in uppercase or lowercase.

Comment: OK. But I did't understand: should `data` match then (with letter `a` more than once), or not match (since `a` repeats not right after the first `a`)?

Comment: The 2 "a" in "data" should match because we are trying to match any letter that occurs more than once in a string. It does not matter if the "a" are not consecutive, as long as they occur more than once in a string, before or after any other letter, the regex should match them because we are only looking for letters that occur more than once in a string.

Comment: That's right, @Emma. What I have explained in the comment above is exactly what we wish to do.

Answer (score 7):

Here, we can simply use a back-reference with an `i` flag:

```
([a-z])\1
```

or without an `i` flag:

```
([A-Za-z])\1
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PVny43/1/)

#### Test

```
re = /([a-z])\1/im
str = 'a
ab
abc
1
22
22AB
AB
ABC
ABBC
ABBCCDD
'

# Print the match result
str.scan(re) do |match|
    puts match.to_s
end
```

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired and you wish to modify it, please visit this link at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/PVny43/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### Edit

My guess is that here we wish to capture the repeating letter here, which this expression might do so:

```
([a-z])(?=[a-z]*\1)
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/u9Cv0v/1)

#### Test

```
re = /([a-z])(?=[a-z]*\1)/
str = 'data
pattern
alice
bob
zdim
avery
paragraph
'

# Print the match result
str.scan(re) do |match|
    puts match.to_s
end
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried using ([A-Za-z]{2,}) but this matches all the letters, no matter if it's just 1 letter or more. For example for the word "data",  I only wanted ([A-Za-z]{2,}) to match the two "a" but it matches all the letters in the word.

Comment: Is “naïve” a word?

Comment: Hi, @AlekseiMatiushkin.  The regex that I'm looking for should not match "naive" because all letters in "naive" only occur once. The regex should match all the letters that repeat themselves in a string.

Comment: ï in naïve was what actually matters in my question.

Answer (score 3):

It would be nice to be able to write:

```
str.gsub(/(.)[^\1]*\z/i, '')
```

but, alas, back-references (`\1`) cannot appear in character classes.

I don't believe the objective can be achieved with a single regular expression, but it could be realised with a sequence of them. I assume the string contains only lowercase letters, for example:

```
str = "bananas"
```

1. Convert letters that are followed later in the string by the same letter to upper case.

```
str1 = str.gsub(/(.)(?=.*\1)/) { |s| s.upcase }
  #=> "bANAnas
```

2. Remove the lowercase letters.

```
str2 = str1.gsub(/\p{Ll}/, '')
  #=> "ANA"
```

3. Remove duplicates of the letters that remain.

```
str3 = str2.gsub(/(.)(?=.*\1)/, '')
  #=> "NA"
```

4. Downcase `str3` if desired.

```
str3.downcase
  #=> "na"
```

`(?=.*\1)` is a *positive lookahead*.

If the requirement that a regular expression be used is lifted, one could write:

```
str.each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |c,h| h[c] += 1 }.
    select { |_,count| count > 1 }.
    keys
  #=> ["a", "n"]
```

Here

```
str.each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |c,h| h[c] += 1 }
  #=> {"b"=>1, "a"=>3, "n"=>2, "s"=>1}
```

This uses the second form of [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-c-new), which takes an argument that is referred to as the *default value*. `h[c] += 1` expands to `h[c] = h[c] + 1`. If `h` does not have a key `c`, `h[c]` on the right of the equality returns the default value of zero, yielding `h[c] = 0 + 1`.

Comment: Since you are already aware of the fact “letter” is not exactly what ignorant users of the Latin alphabet call “letter,” would you mind to make it work for poor Germans? :) `"ü".match(/\p{Ll}/) #⇒ #<MatchData "u">` but `"ü".unicode_normalize(:nfc).match(/\p{Ll}/) #⇒ #<MatchData "ü">`.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a regular expression here.

```
"bananas".
    downcase.
    unicode_normalize(:nfc).
    each_char.
    with_object([Set.new, []]) do |e, (result, temp)|
  (temp.include?(e) ? result : temp) << e
end.first.to_a.join
#⇒ "an"
```

or:

```
"bananas".
    downcase.
    unicode_normalize(:nfc).
    chars.
    group_by(&:itself).
    reject { |_, e| e.count == 1 }.
    keys.
    join
#⇒ "an"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely have to use regular expressions, you can first sort the characters in your input string and then use a regex to check for repeating characters (I shamelessly stole the regex from @AlekseiMatiushkin's answer):

```
input = "A man a plan a canal Panama - Äpfelsäure".split()

re = /(\p{Ll})\1/

input.each do |w|
  sorted = w.downcase.unicode_normalize(:nfc).chars.sort().join()
  puts w if sorted =~ re
end
```

Comment: C’mon, you live in München, you should know why `"ä" == "ä" #⇒ false` (the example is copy-pasteable.) The code above will fail on combined diacritics, `String#unicode_normalize(:nfc)` call is mandatory before calling `chars`. Try e. g. `"Äpfelsäure"` :)